# How do I avoid this unexpected behaviour when redirecting output from echo?

Tags: io-redirection, echo

I wanted to add to my hosts file easily using a one line command, but I get an unexpected result.

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo -e "10.0.10.0\tserver.bananas.com\tserver" >> /etc/hosts'

$ cat /etc/hosts
-e 10.0.10.0        server.bananas.com        server
```

I'm using the -e switch on echo to enable the use of backslash escapes for the tabs, but the -e is being included in the redirected output.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Your `sh` is likely a shell (such as `dash`) whose `echo` built-in  doesn't have a `-e` switch

Comment: Related: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why echo is failing as per your question, but in general, I'd use `printf` instead. It's much more predictable in its output.

```
printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' '10.0.10.0' 'server.bananas.com' 'server'
```

#### Explanation

- `%s\t%s\t%s\n`: this part explains what the output format will be, i.e. a string, a tab, a string, a tab, a string, a newline.
- The three strings are the following arguments supplied to `printf`.

#### Writing to root-owned files

Also, I'm not sure if you are aware, but instead of using the `sudo sh -c` construct, you could use `sudo tee` instead. i.e.

```
printf … | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

I find this more convenient, especially when it avoids having to escape characters inside the external `'`.